# Can elasticsearch 2.2 client library work with older version of elasticsearch 1.3

Tags: elasticsearch

A feature in my project is already using 1.3 of elasticsearch and for new feature the plan is to use ES 2.2 also it is for some reasons that I cannot upgrade existing ES 1.3 to ES 2.2

Can one single version of elasticsearch client library (preferably 2.2) work with  both versions of ES 1.3 and ES 2.2?

I know ES has changed a lot of their APIs from 2.0 but curious to know if someone has tried this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Java client must be from the same major version of Elasticsearch
>   as the nodes; otherwise, they may not be able to understand each
>   other. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html